# How can I add a custom button by using a custom module in Magento 2.3?

Tags: module, cart, blocks, magento2.3, extensions

I wanted to add my own button in the Shopping Cart as I tried to show you in the screenshot.

[image]

But I didn't find a tutorial that worked for me. Do you have any idea how I can do this? (I want to make my own extension)

(EDIT) This is what I have done so far:

In the registration.php file:

```
<?php
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
 );
```

In the module.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

In the Button.php file:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;
class Button extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

}
```

In the checkout_cart_index.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <referenceContainer name="cart.summary">
                <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Button" after="-" name="custom_button" template="Vendor_ModuleName::button.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

In the button.phtml file:

```
<button>Your Button</button>
```

I also ran all commands you have told me.

Comment: Are you using a custom theme?

Comment: No I am not using a custom Theme. I actually did almost nothing in my Magento 2 Website. The only thing I made was my first own Module to learn how to make Modules in Magento.

Comment: check my answer if u getting any issue let me know

Comment: now in `checkout_cart_index` add `ModuleName` instead of `Module` in block class

Comment: well, I am stupid, i will try if it works

Comment: It works, you are the best man. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: One more question: Is there also a possibility to get the css of the Proceed To Checkout Button. That my own button looks exactly the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a Custom Module as Follows

> Vendor\ModuleName\registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

then

> Vendor\ModuleName\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
       <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
       </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

After that run following Command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Add this is Your

> Vendor\ModuleName\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <referenceContainer name="cart.summary">
                <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Button" after="-" name="custom_button" template="Vendor_ModuleName::button.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Now in

> Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Button.php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;

```
class Button extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

}
```

then in

> Vendor\ModuleName\view\frontend\templates\button.phtml

```
<button>Your Button</button>
```

Comment: This is not working, sorry. Any other ideas?

Comment: is should work. have u create a module??

Comment: Yes, but now the cart page is empty, any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I fixed the page, but i cant see the button, I created

Comment: check answer now

Comment: I did what you said in the new answer, but it isnt working again. I dont see the button in my shopping cart

Comment: can you add each file code in your question which you have done so far??

Comment: I added all my code.

Comment: Wait it didnt copy proberly i get the code again

Comment: Now the question is edited right

Answer (score 0):

Waqar Ali's answer is almost correct. The **registration.php** file is missing:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Vendor_ModuleName',
__DIR__
);
```

and the Vendor/ModuleName/Block/Button.php file needs to define namespace:

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;
```

Don't to forget:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I did this and now the page works, but i dont see any button

Comment: Try **checkout.cart.container** instead **cart.summary** . Don't to forget flush cache.

Comment: Waqar Ali solved it for me, but thanks

Comment: I stay happy to know :)